# C++ switch statement expression evaluation guarantee

Tags: c++, standards, language-lawyer

Regarding switch the standard states the following. *"When the switch statement is executed, its condition is evaluated and compared with each case constant."*

Does it mean that the condition expression evaluated once and once only, and it is guaranteed by the standard for each compiler?

For example, when a function is used in the switch statement head, with a side effect.

```
int f() { ... }
switch (f())
{
    case ...;
    case ...;
}
```

Comment: It's like asking whether `int main() { putchar('c'); }` is guaranteed to call `putchar` only once (and thus is guaranteed to print only one 'c'). Really, I'm not aware of any text in the standard that provides such guarantee.

Comment: I disagree. switch is a special statement, which can be implemented in several effective ways in assembly. For me it is not as obvious.

Comment: I think cpplearner is right, the "several effective ways in assembly" are permitted under the 'as-if' rule. Aside of that the guarantee that your function calls (which have side effects) are evaluated once, *in every context* in C++, are the same, irrespectable of what kind of context is that.

Comment: @mikk: can you think of a good reason why an optimizer would evaluate the expression several times ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust: of course not :) but the question was if it is guaranteed or not.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I think it is guaranteed that `f` is only called once.

First we have

> The condition shall be of integral type, enumeration type, or class type.

[6.4.2 (1)] (the non-integral stuff does not apply here), and

> The value of a condition that is an expression is the value of the
>   expression

[6.4 (4)]. Furthermore,

> The value of the condition will be referred to as simply “the condition” where the
>   usage is unambiguous.

[6.4 (4)] That means in our case, the "condition" is just a plain value of type  `int`, not `f`. `f` is only used to find the value for the condition. Now when control reaches the `switch` statement

> its condition is evaluated

[6.4.2 (5)], i.e. we use the value of the `int` that is returned by `f` as our "condition". Then finally the condition (which is a value of type `int`, not `f`), is

> compared with each case constant

[6.4.2 (5)]. This will not trigger side effects from `f` again.

All quotes from N3797. (Also checked N4140, no difference)

Comment: N3797 is an intermediate draft, consider using N4139/N4140 for C++14, or N3337 for C++11

Comment: @MattMcNabb Are they available for free? (And for this question, are they different?)

Comment: I think the ambuguity of the OP arises from the parsing of the sentence as `its condition is evaluated (and compared with each case constant)` or `(its condition is evaluated and compared with) each case constant` which has nothing to do with the typing of the condition.

Comment: An expression may be of `integral type` - I don't think you're quoting the relevant section.

Comment: @pqnet Well it is in the sense that if what I wrote was actually true, we would compare integers, which never has side effects. So it would answer the question.

Comment: @BaummitAugen oh so the statement was in order to exclude that the actual comparison itself could have been overloaded with side effects.

Comment: @pqnet The question here is whether we will end up with sth. like `f() == 1` or `someInt == 1`. I argued for the latter, but with Beyelers Remark, I feel like this is not done yet.

Comment: @BeyelerStudios Thanks, I tried to further support the anser with more quotes.

Comment: Yes that's the right section (see my previous answer) ;)

Comment: @BeyelerStudios Oh, sorry, I did not read the other answers yet.

Answer (score 5):

Reading [N4296](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf)

Page 10 para 14:

> Every value computation and side effect associated with a full-expression is sequenced before every value
>   computation and side effect associated with the next full-expression to be evaluated.

When I read the first line of para. 10 (above that):

> A full-expression is an expression that is not a sub-expression of
>   another expression.

I have to believe that the condition of a `switch` statement is a full-expression and each condition expression is a full expression (albeit trivial at execution).

A `switch` is a statement not an expression (see 6.4.2 and many other places).

So by that reading the evaluation of the `switch` must take place before the evaluation of the `case` constants.

As ever many points boil down to tortuous reading of the specification to come to an obvious conclusion.

If I peer reviewed that sentence I would propose the following amendment (in **bold**):

> When the switch statement is executed, its condition is evaluated
>   **once per execution of the switch statement** and compared with each case constant.

Comment: Why do you believe that the controlling expression in a switch statement is not a full expression?  Clearly it is an expression, so what larger expression do you think it is part of?

Comment: @BenVoigt I cannot believe it isn't a full-expression for the reason you give. I've edited my sentence. Hopefully that makes it clearer.

Comment: If you could reword to avoid the double negative it would help (especially because the two parts are separated like they are).

Comment: As of C++11, a full expression is defined as "...an expression that is not part of another full-expression (such as...conditional expression of if/switch...)". -- https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order

Comment: @Avi I quoted from a late draft of the C++14 Standard which I believe stands. While cppreference.com is a great site it's not all a direct quote from the standard.
So if we're in language lawyer mode it's not admissible. But it all boils down to the same thing. The condition expression of a switch is a full expression and full y evaluated before its side-effects.
Outside language lawyer land it would be bonkers if adding or removing case statements could have a side-effect!

Answer (score 3):

Yes the expression is evaluated only once when the switch statement is executed:

**§ 6.4 Selection statements**

> 4 [...] The value of a condition that is an expression is the value of the
>   expression [...] The value of the condition will be referred to as simply “the condition” where the usage is unambiguous.

This means that the expression is evaluated and its value is considered the `condition` to be evaluated against each `case` statement.

Answer (score 2):

Section 6.4.4:

> ...The value of a condition that is an expression is the value of the
>   expression, contextually converted to bool for statements other than
>   switch;...The value of the condition will be referred to as simply “the condition” where the
>   usage is unambiguous

In my understanding, the quote above is equivalent to the following pseudo-code:

```
switchCondition := evaluate(expression)
```

Now add your quote

> ...its condition is evaluated and compared with each case constant.

Which should be translated to:

```
foreach case in cases
    if case.constant == switchCondition
         goto case.block
```

So yeah, it looks like this is the case.

Answer (score 2):

Does this code print `hello` once or twice?

```
int main() {
    printf("hello\n");
}
```

Well, I think the answer is in the more general understanding of what the standard describes rather than in the specific `switch` statement wording.

As per **Program execution [intro.execution]** the standard describes the behaviour of some *abstract machine* that *executes* the program parsed according to the C++ *grammar*. It does not really define what 'abstract machine' or 'executes' mean, but they are assumed to mean their obvious computer science concepts, i.e. a computer that goes through the abstract syntax tree and evaluates every part of it according to the semantics described by the standard. This implies that if you wrote something once, then when the *execution* gets to that point, it is evaluated only once.

The more relevant question is "when the implementation may evaluate something not the way written in the program"? For this there is the as-if rule and a bunch of undefined behaviours which permit the implementation to deviate from this abstract interpretation.

Answer (score 2):

This issue was clarified for C++ '20 making it clear that the condition is evaluated once:

> When the switch statement is executed, its condition is evaluated. If one of the case constants has the same value as the condition, control is passed to the statement following the matched case label.

The commit message for the [change](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/commit/6997ed2799111ddf57dfa49418be581adfd7c03b#diff-13fc6b16fa109524b40c062ee3237f51a962cf67a4c19efe5b3d69148e74813f) acknowledges that it was potentially confusing before:

> [stmt.switch] Clarify comparison for case labels

Answer (score 0):

The expression is guaranteed that is evaluated only once by the flow of control. This  is justified in the standard N4431 *§6.4.2/6 The switch statement [stmt.switch]* (**Emphasis mine**):

> **case and default labels in themselves do not alter the flow of
>   control, which continues unimpeded across such labels.** To exit from a
>   switch, see break, 6.6.1. [ Note: Usually, the substatement that is
>   the subject of a switch is compound and case and default labels appear
>   on the top-level statements contained within the (compound)
>   substatement, but this is not required. Declarations can appear in the
>   substatement of a switch-statement. — end note ]

Comment: I think this quote only defines the implicit fallthrough.

Comment: @BaummitAugen IMHO the above quote from the standard gives implicitly an explicit justification that the condition will be evaluated only once since otherwise flow control will be violated.